# systemd script to only run on demand

Tags: systemd

I have set up a systemd script that is working.
I want it to only run when I call it, but currently it is also running on reboot.
How can I make the script not run on reboot, but only when I call it (as in: `sudo service systemdname start`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux.

It sounds like your service is "enabled" to start at boot. To disable it from starting on boot:

```
systemctl disable your-service-name
```

It's possible your service could be started anyway on boot if another service depends on it.

Also note that `service` is not a `systemd` command. The `service` command was used with `Upstart` and `SysVinit` init systems and has been made compatible with `systemd`. The `systemd`-specific way to start a service would be:

```
sudo systemctl start your-service-name
```

Comment: Nice, that is a simple way to do it. Thanks !

Comment: One more question: After running:
`sudo systemctl start your-service-name`
Will the service still be disabled ?

Comment: Yes. You have to explicitly `enable` a service to start at boot.

Comment: I use virtualbox, one of the services is vboxdrv, but disabling that means that it is NOT started when I open virtualbox, so it seems either you have it enabled -- and it starts at boot -- or disabled and it doesn't start at all. I could make a script to start it before I open virtualbox (eg add it to the .desktop file) but I'd have thought it could be launched on demand more easily?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the service:

```
systemctl disable myservice
```

`enable` and `disable` control the on-boot behavior of services in systemd